# How to I make a 5x5 in this way

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to make [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOH7M.png) for the whole last 2 hours, I have tried this and I am not getting any Error.

[image]

```
public class Truefalse {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int nums[][] = new int[5][5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            for (int j=0;j<5; j++){
                if (j!=i) {
                    nums[i][j]=0;
                } else if (j==i) {
                    nums[i][j]=1;
                }
                System.out.print(nums[i][j]);
                System.out.println();
           } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: @MortenSickel Output: `1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1`

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid description of the problem you have. What is your problem?

Comment: @MortenSickel your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11087393) doesn't describe what OP has, what what OP wants (which is already shown in linked picture).

Comment: Bah, you're right, I misread Coffeekids output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `System.out.println();` out of the inner for-loop.

```
public class truefalse {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      int nums[][] = new int[5][5];
      for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
          for (int j=0;j<5; j++){
              if(j!=i){
                  nums[i][j]=0;
              } else if(j==i){
                  nums[i][j]=1;
              }
              System.out.print(nums[i][j]);
           }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Output of this code is

```
10000
01000
00100
00010
00001
```

Comment: View output of this answer [here](https://ideone.com/wzpw56)

Comment: Vielen Dank herr Stefan!

Answer (score 0):

```
int nums[][] = new int[5][5];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  for (int j=0;j<5; j++) {
    if(j!=i) {
      nums[i][j]=0;
    } else if(j==i) {
      nums[i][j]=1;
    }
    System.out.print(nums[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: lol.. he edited his answer. His first answer was one one line as a comment...

Comment: Ok sorry, it came up in review que, thats why I asked.